# Center aligning child div, while parent has padding

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I have a Parent div with padding left of 16px (1rem), I decided to center align "only first child", considering the 16px of parent padding. I'm using tailwindcss BTW.

here is my code:

```
<div class="flow-root w-[300px] pl-4 h-[200px]">
    <div class="">this child should be center</div>

    <div class=""></div>

    <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

1- keep in mind i have to use display:flow-root because otherwise I face another bug.

2- margin left and right : auto is not working for child because it's also adding parent's padding  (then it's not center).

3- tried position relative and then right-[16px] and then again margin left and right auto which didnt work either on different screen sizes.

4- if by any case you don't know tailwind, CSS help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you want the text inside to be centered or the element itself?

Comment: element @Wongjn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider adding `margin-right` that is the same amount as the `padding-left` so that the `margin-right` "offsets" the right edge by the same amount of spacing, thus making the `<div>` centered within the parent:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flow-root w-[300px] pl-4 h-[200px] border border-red-500">
    <div class="mr-4 bg-green-500">this child should be center</div>

    <div class=""></div>

    <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

---

Here is an additional solution for if the child has a fixed width of `100px` to address the comment from OP. You could apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` and then offset the parent `padding-left` by applying half of the parent `padding-left` by applying `transform: translateX()` equal to negative half of the `padding-left`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flow-root w-[300px] pl-4 h-[200px] border border-red-500">
    <div class="mx-auto w-[100px] -translate-x-2 bg-green-500">this child should be center</div>

    <div class=""></div>

    <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this can be right answer in the case that child has no width. try giving child a 100px width and you can see it's no longer center.

Comment: Consider specifying all stipulations for the problem in your question from the outset rather than piecemeal as and when answers are received. I have updated my answer with an additional solution that addresses the newly added stipulation from your comment.